# C#: GroupBox borders are drawn incorrectly, using WPF and XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, groupbox

This is what my groupBox looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZQgs.png
There is nothing placed on top of the groupBox or anything like  that. Some groupboxes are correct, some are not. I have no clue what's wrong :-/

I intended to disable hardware graphics support to see if there was a change, but the registry path given in the msdn-guide wasn't found on this computer.

I'm running WinXP and using an internal intel graphics card.

Comment: curious, could it be an aliasing problem? border thickness appears very thin, so in areas where anti-aliasing is applied (corners and super sampling *between lines*) it may not render correctly. what happens if you beef up its thickness? or apply a darker colour?

Comment: I think it may your computer's problem or wpf rendering problem. Try to find out that on other computer, if.

Answer (score 1):

Run it on a different computer, try to reproduce the problem.  If the problem is not reproducable then its likely something to do with that computer and there's nothing in code that's going to fix it (which I suspect is probably the case).

Comment: Thanks! I tried running on a computer with a different graphics card (ran on two with same one before asking here) and the problem was not present. Managed to remove the problem completely by setting render mode to software:
`RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;`

Comment: Try updating the video driver. That's fixed issues for me before now.